# GGplot geom_line works but ggplotly() only connect points of identical continuous values

Tags: ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, ggplotly

I can create a coloured graph in ggplot where the `geom_line()` works as expected. However, when I pipe to `ggplotly()` , the line starts/ends at seemingly randon data points. How can I make it look like this, but with a tooltip?

[image]

Instead of: [image]

```
libary(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# df
data <- structure(list( Percent = c(0.32, 0.23, 0.75, 0.25, 0.482, 0.421, 0.5114, 0.3423, 0.27, 0.4324, 0.347, 0.377, 0.26, 
0.375, 0.18604, 0.241378, 0.3095, 0.348837209, 0.33333, 0.1875, 0.2820, 0.65, 0.72, 0.75, 0.81, 0.87, 0.8244), finalpoint = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.8244), date = structure(c(18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 
18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 18718, 18748, 18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18962, 18993, 19024, 19052), class = "Date"),  Status_perc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,   2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("<70%", "70-80%", "≥80%"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


# create and save plot
test <- data %>% 
    ggplot( aes ( x = date, y = Percent,
                label = finalpoint , 
                colour= Percent, 
                group = 1)) +   # Note sure why, but I have to add this
    geom_line(  ) +
  geom_point ( ) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(finalpoint), "", sprintf("%1.1f%%",finalpoint*100))) , 
            nudge_y = +0.2, nudge_x = -50  ) +                # Add label for final point, formatted as %.
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", 
                         limits = c(0,1)) 


# Pipe through ggplotly for interactivity
test %>% plotly::ggplotly( ) %>%
#  tooltip =  c("Percent", "edtriage", "Num_Denom" , ")) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Comment: It will work if You remove `colour= Percent` in `aes`

Comment: @KacZdr but then I lose the colours. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Note: I replaced `geom_line()` with `geom_link2()` from the `ggforce` package to get a better gradient line in ggplot, but received `Warning: geom_GeomPathInterpolate() has yet to be implemented in plotly.` :( Any workarounds?